# File Manager with CKEditor

Tags: php, file-upload, open-source, ckeditor

I'm using KCFinder with CKEditor but I'm quite not satisfied with it. Is there any free file manager that I can use with CKEditor?

Answer (score 2):

[Jasfinder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasfinder/) is another one that that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

use ckeditor file browser plugin or pdw file browser

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdwfilebrowser/